# Visual Studio working with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Tags: c#, office-interop

I'm developing a small tool to grab emails from Outlook in C#. 
Below code works fine

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.Folders["mymailbox@provider.nl"].Folders["specificFolder"];
```

but is it possible to replace the specific mailbox and folder with variables to make it flexibel?

The below doesn't work as the program ends in error, saying that it can't find the object:

```
string MailBox="mymailbox@provider.nl";
string MailFolder="specificFolder";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox =    
    mapiNameSpace.Folders[MailBox].Folders[MailFolder];
```

Comment: Are you sure that's your code? If the first way worked, then the 2nd way would. The code doesn't care whether it comes from a string literal or a variable. Also, the title of your question is misleading - it makes it sounds like you want Outlook to work with Visual Studio, but VS really has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was more simple than I thought, although not quit clear.
Although both `MailBox` and `MailFolder` were defined as type `string` I had to change the code to below to get it working

```
string MailBox="mymailbox@provider.nl";
string MailFolder="specificFolder";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox =    
    mapiNameSpace.Folders[MailBox.ToString()].Folders[MailFolder.ToString()];
```